# Keep data in 3 HTML forms while data is submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have 3 HTML forms (it is mandatory for my purpose to have 3 separate forms)

Each form consists of the following:

1. Business name text (input) - Form 1
2. Primary Category (dropdown menu) - Form 2
3. Secondary Category (dropdown menu) - Form 3

As the Primary Category is changed, the Secondary Category is changed. This works fine.

What is note working is the Business name text. Whenver I change the Primary or the secondary category the values in the input file are lost.

Forms 2 and 3 are 'submitted using a javascript as follows' -

```
echo '<select name="primary_category" size = "7" onChange="document.getElementById(\'CatForm1\').submit();"> ';
```

and

```
echo '<select name="secondary_category" size = "7" onChange="document.getElementById(\'CatForm2\').submit();"> ';
```

The business name html form is as follows:

```
echo '<form method="post" id="CatForm0">';

?>
<input id="business_name" name="business_name" tabindex="auto" value="
<?php if(isset($_POST['business_name'])) { echo ($_SESSION['business_name']); }?>" type="text" />

<?php 
echo '</form>';
```

Whenver I change the Primary or the secondary category the values in the input file are lost. I'd like to keep the value in the business_name input box.

Comment: You may need to submit via AJAX instead of using `submit()`. In most (all?) browsers, a `submit` triggers a page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The code here is untested and would likely have to be heavily adapted to work for your application. But it should be enough to show the direction I'm suggesting:
There are a couple of options as I see it:

**A)** Create one form. You then use javascript to change the `action` attribute of the form tag

```
document.getElementById("CatForm0").action = "newpage.php";
```

depending on which page you want to submit to. If in your PHP script you are referring to form names like `$_POST["name"]` then the extra values that come with the submit will be ignored. You can then use the values back in the form fields like `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>" />` to write the values back into the fields.

**B)** Use some events on the business name box to copy anything the user inputs into the business name field into a hidden field in the other forms.

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" id="CatForm0">';
?>
<input id="business_name" name="business_name" tabindex="auto" value="
<?php if(isset($_POST['business_name'])) { echo ($_SESSION['business_name']); }?>" type="text"
onblur="CopyValues()" onkeyup="CopyValues()" onclick="CopyValues()" />

<?php 
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Then in the other forms include the business name field as hidden fields

```
<form id="pri_cat">
    <input type="hidden" id="bus_name_1" name="bus_name_1" value="" />
</form>
<form id="second_cat">
    <input type="hidden" id="bus_name_2" name="bus_name_2" value="" />
</form>
```

Then for the javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CopyValues() {
        var val = document.getElementById("business_name").value;
        document.getElementById("bus_name_1").value = val;
        document.getElementById("bus_name_2").value = val;
    }
</script>
```

Then in the PHP, you can set the value of the hidden field into `$_SESSION['business_name']`.

**C)** Use AJAX to submit the form and use the return values to populate the other form.

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" id="CatForm0">';
?>
<input id="business_name" name="business_name" tabindex="auto" value="
<?php if(isset($_POST['business_name'])) { echo ($_SESSION['business_name']); }?>" type="text" />
<?php 
echo '</form>';
?>

<form id="CatForm1" action="thispage.php" method="post">
    <?php
    echo '<select id="primary_category" name="primary_category" size = "7" onchange="SubmitCat1();"> ';
    ?>
</form>

<form id="CatForm2" action="thispage.php" method="post">
    <?php
    echo '<select id="secondary_category" name="secondary_category" size = "7" onchange="SubmitCat2();"> ';
    ?>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitCat1() {
        var val = document.getElementById("primary_category").value;
        var xmlhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.open("POST","thispage.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                //If you are returning JSON data from the post...
                var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                //then do something with the data

                //If you're returning HTML from the post, you can wrap the second form in 
                // a <div> and set the HTML
                var div = document.getElementById("form2_div").innerHtml = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send("primary_category="+escape(val));
    }
</script>
```

This would need to be done for each form you want to submit. This last route is the one that was suggested in the comments. It's also the route that MVC type systems make common use of. Submitting forms via AJAX and then doing something with the return data is a common task.